# Parse PFQueryTableView Pin Objects in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, local-storage, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

The App should be usable when there is no internet connection but also load/update new objects from the backend when the internet connection is available again.

Is it possible to pin the objects in my `PFQueryTableViewController` and only load from my parse-backend when there is internet connection?

Right now I have this in my `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    PFObject.pinAllInBackground(self.objects, block: { (succeeded, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
        }else {
            println(error!.userInfo)
        }
    })
}
```

and this in my `queryForTable()`

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

    var query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName!)

    query.fromLocalDatastore()

    return query
}
```

The result is that my `PFQueryTableViewController` doesn't load any Objects any more.
What am I missing?

I'm using Swift!

Comment: You don't actually have any objects in your `object` variable. You need to add objects to that variable first.

Comment: well im using PFQueryTableViewController and dont creat any array of objects. I only tell which class i want to load from my parse account.

Comment: Yeah but when that `viewDidLoad` method is called, `self.objects` is an empty array because the `PFQueryTableViewController` hasn't loaded any objects from the server. So in essence, you're pining an empty array of objects.

Comment: so where should i pin it?